# Bitwise operations performed on an 8 bit unsigned int

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, uint8t

In the following code, bitwise operations are performed on an 8-bit unsigned integer.

```
uint8_t i = 10;
uint8_t j = i>>2;
```

In this example, `i` is promoted to a `signed int` and value assigned to 8 bits unsigned int. Is it safe to int converted back to 8 bits unsigned int?

Comment: I don't think it matters: assignment will truncate the result anyway. And with your values it's not an issue. but your question has a lot of typos. Can you edit it?

Comment: The shift operation is subject to integer promotion.

Comment: since you're dividing, the result will be the same.

Comment: And I don't really see what exactly are you asking here. Are you asking if it is guaranteed to result in `2`? Yes it is.

Comment: not 5, rather 2.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah, sorry

Comment: I like those manual compilation exercises :)

Comment: Why are you asking this?

Comment: The last sentence still doesn't make sense grammatically.

Comment: *after the edit* - the conversion process is covered by the standard [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3) .It is safe to covert any integer to an unsigned integer type in terms it is always well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

In arithmetic expressions, the lesser types are converted to `int` if possible, and otherwise to `unsigned int` (see [6.3.1.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2)).

Practically,

```
uint8_t i = 10;
puts(_Generic(i>>2, uint8_t: "u8", int: "int", unsigned int: "uint"));
```

should output "int", as should

```
uint8_t i = 10, j = 2;
puts(_Generic(i>>j, uint8_t: "u8", int: "int", unsigned int: "uint"));
```

(In the former example, `i` would also get promoted to `int` because `2` is of type `int` and because [usual arithmetic conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) would apply.)